# How to put a not null constraint on a custom type?

Tags: sql, postgresql

A lot of my tables must be timestamped, so my idea was to define a custom type, and to create my tables with columns from this type:

```sql
CREATE TYPE timestamped AS (
    created_at timestamp NOT NULL,
    updated_at timestamp NOT NULL,
    deleted_at timestamp
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS objects (
    LIKE timestamped INCLUDING ALL,
    id uuid NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    -- etc.
);
```

There is a syntax error on the `NOT NULL`:

```
LINE 2:     created_at timestamp NOT NULL,
                                 ^
```

How can I say that this value must be defined?

Comment: `NOT NULL` is not allowed in a user-defined type.  Nor are constraints and other features that actual rows support.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, user-defined types don't allow constraints.

But, user-defined domains do.  So you can do what you want as:

```
CREATE DOMAIN required_timestamp as timestamp
    check (value is not null);

CREATE TYPE timestamped AS (
    created_at required_timestamp,
    updated_at required_timestamp,
    deleted_at timestamp
);
```

Comment: For those who need the information, note that a DOMAIN can handle a default value: `CREATE DOMAIN required_timestamp AS timestamp CHECK (value IS NOT NULL)
DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;`